# Integrating QR codes for event attendance

Tags: civievent, extension

Would like to check-in event participants using a QR code that will also update the attendance status of the participant. Is there an extension available for this feature? Any help is appreciated...thanks

Answer (score 4):

We have built such a solution, though no extension is available.

The key is that the QR Code simply needs to contain a URL request, with embedded querystring parameters such as event_id and participant_id. Pretty much any stock QR scanning app will recognize it as a URL, and will simply pass it on to the device's browser.

We wrote a simple PHP program that was called in the URL, that grabbed the querystring parameters (event_id and contact_id in our case), and called the CiviCRM API to change the participant status to 'Attended'.

Our app also returned a screen back to the device browser that reflected add-ons that the participant had purchased (lunches in our case).

This does have a bit of a security risk.  We got around this risk, by having a separate URL the device browser would be directed to that the user could log into and have a cookie dropped onto their device (which was then subsequently interrogated by the main PHP script to validate).

Answer (score 3):

We created an event app for one of our clients which enables the participant status to be updated via a QR code. More info here: https://vedaconsulting.co.uk/event-manager-app

Do send us an email if you have any further questions info@vedaconsulting.co.uk

Many thanks

Daniella

Comment: Hi Daniella, thanks for your response, that actually helps. The issue here is, we dont have an app yet. I need to generate a QR code for my participants and scan the same using any scanning app that will update my CiviCRM database. I can generate a QR code, but I am not sure how to update my CiviCRM DB after the scanning is done.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it exists already but I do know Circle Interactive have worked with barcodes and QR codes in a few previous projects: -
https://civicrm.org/blog/andyw/bitcoin-payment-processing-with-bitpay

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your response, but that's got to do with enabling bit coin's with CiviCRM...may be it will be of use to me sometime down the line :)